# What PayPal API should I use?

Tags: paypal

I am creating a project whereby users are able to create webstores for their customers to purchase items from.

My current two thoughts are:

1. Payouts API whereby all customer payments will go to myself, and I will then use the Payouts API to send payments to users.
2. Have users enter in their API credentials in their user area so that their customers can send money directly to them using the Express Checkout API

Neither of these options feel optimal - the payouts API means I will be responsible for all chargebacks and payment disputes between customer and user. Forcing the user to enter in their API credentials is a slightly better solution however it would require me to provide documentation and support on how to create their API credentials.

I will likely go with option 2, but I'm hoping someone may be able to provide more options that I've overlooked or not seen in the docs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is correct, it is what all third party shopping carts do.

There exists a third option, the `payee` field, but you run into permission issues for refunds and authorizations. So Option 2 is the correct one for your use case. Each receiver should create a REST APP and enter the ClientID/Secret into your system.

You mentioned the "Express Checkout API" so you might be using something old/classic, which you should not do. See this front-end demo pattern of Smart Payment Buttons: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Notice the two fetches to '/demo/...' endpoints, which must be replaced with actual routes on your server. The first should create a v2/order and return an OrderID. The second should capture that v2/order after a payer has approved it.